# xcode cannot detect the flutter plugins

Tags: flutter, xcode

when I try to run the Flutter project on vscode looks like Xcode cannot detect the plugins. that the output when I try to run with the plugins:

`Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'flutter_secure_storage' not found /Users/dijitalgen/Desktop/is_takip_uyg_projesi_2/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8`

that the output without plugins:

`Error (Xcode): The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.`

when I delete the plugins the app runs perfectly. I'm sure the podfile and deployment info ios versions match and did tons of flutter clean/ pub get/ pod install/ update/ build ios but still the same.

here is the plugin implementation code that throws an error in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m file

```
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<flutter_native_splash/FlutterNativeSplashPlugin.h>)
#import <flutter_native_splash/FlutterNativeSplashPlugin.h>
#else
@import flutter_native_splash;
#endif

#if __has_include(<flutter_secure_storage/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.h>)
#import <flutter_secure_storage/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.h>
#else
@import flutter_secure_storage;
#endif

#if __has_include(<image_gallery_saver/ImageGallerySaverPlugin.h>)
#import <image_gallery_saver/ImageGallerySaverPlugin.h>
#else
@import image_gallery_saver;
#endif

#if __has_include(<image_picker_ios/FLTImagePickerPlugin.h>)
#import <image_picker_ios/FLTImagePickerPlugin.h>
#else
@import image_picker_ios;
#endif

#if __has_include(<path_provider_foundation/PathProviderPlugin.h>)
#import <path_provider_foundation/PathProviderPlugin.h>
#else
@import path_provider_foundation;
#endif

#if __has_include(<permission_handler_apple/PermissionHandlerPlugin.h>)
#import <permission_handler_apple/PermissionHandlerPlugin.h>
#else
@import permission_handler_apple;
#endif
```

tried like every terminal code, rebuilt the project over and over again but no.